# Is the Shebang (#!) standardized?

Tags: posix, standards, language-lawyer, shebang, lsb

Is the [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) `#!`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

in front of script executables officially standardized in the Linux Standard Base or in any of The Open Group standards or elsewhere? If yes, please provide references and details.

NOTE: I'm most interested in its meaning for shell scripts as well as for any executable file. In other words, do any of the standards require shebang-like interpretation of `#!` at the beginning of executable files? However, any other references to it in the standards are also welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) leaves the effect of `#!` unspecified. From *2.1 Shell Introduction*

> The shell reads its input from a file (see sh), from the -c option or from the system() and popen() functions defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008. If the first line of a file of shell commands starts with the characters "#!", the results are unspecified.

Comment: The citation is about the shell command language. The quoted section is saying that the results of `sh foo` are unspecified if `foo` has a shebang (that is, if its first line begins with #!), but it says nothing about executing `./foo` directly.

Answer (score 2):

From the [source](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-16.html):

> Bash scripts often begin with #! /bin/bash (assuming that Bash has
>   been installed in /bin), since this ensures that Bash will be used to
>   interpret the script, even if it is executed under another shell.

You can also check this [The #! magic, details about the shebang/hash-bang mechanism on various Unix flavours](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/)